# How to remove the white space of the first displayed equation only?

Tags: white-space

I want to remove the white space of the first displayed equation only without interfering other equations that follow.

If I activate `\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax` then the remaining displayed equations after `\intertext` also get affected.

I also tried the following but it does not work.

```
\documentclass[margin=0mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\newdimen\temp
\temp=\abovedisplayskip

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align}
\abovedisplayskip=\temp
ax + by &= c\label{eqn:one}\\
px + qy &= r\label{eqn:two}\\
%
\intertext{Multiplying equation~\eqref{eqn:one} by $p$ and equation~\eqref{eqn:two} by $a$, we have}
apx + bpy &= cp\label{eqn:three}\\
apx + aqy &= ar\label{eqn:four}\\
%
\intertext{Subtracting equation~\eqref{eqn:four} from equation~\eqref{eqn:three}, we obtain}
(bp-aq)y &= cp-ar
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

How to avoid such interference?

## Minimal Working Example

```
\documentclass[margin=0mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}
%\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align}
ax + by &= c\label{eqn:one}\\
px + qy &= r\label{eqn:two}\\
%
\intertext{Multiplying equation~\eqref{eqn:one} by $p$ and equation~\eqref{eqn:two} by $a$, we have}
apx + bpy &= cp\label{eqn:three}\\
apx + aqy &= ar\label{eqn:four}\\
%
\intertext{Subtracting equation~\eqref{eqn:four} from equation~\eqref{eqn:three}, we obtain}
(bp-aq)y &= cp-ar
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}\begin{align}`?

Comment: Save and restore won't work, because `align` (and others) read the content as an argument and evaluate it delayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to get rid of this whitespace in a one-off situation for cropping purposes it is easiest to just manually remove it by doing

```
\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}
```

There will be some residual whitespace above the first equation whose size is equal the difference between `\baselineskip` and the font size.

```
\documentclass[margin=0mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{palatino}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}
\begin{align}
ax + by &= c\label{eqn:one}\\
px + qy &= r\label{eqn:two}\\
%
\intertext{Multiplying equation~\eqref{eqn:one} by $p$ and equation~\eqref{eqn:two} by $a$, we have}
apx + bpy &= cp\label{eqn:three}\\
apx + aqy &= ar\label{eqn:four}\\
%
\intertext{Subtracting equation~\eqref{eqn:four} from equation~\eqref{eqn:three}, we obtain}
(bp-aq)y &= cp-ar
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To remove the residual space you have to back up all the spaces which are inserted by `amsmath` and then skip back down the font size.

```
[...]
\makeatletter
\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}
\vspace*{-\ht\strutbox@}
\vspace*{-\dp\strutbox@}
\vspace*{-\lineskip}
\vspace*{\csname f@size\endcsname pt}
\makeatother
\begin{align}
[...]
```

I'm still lacking something.  There is still about 1pt to the upper edge but I don't know what that is.

[image]

Comment: How to remove the residual?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity - Just change `\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}` to `\vspace*{-1.25\abovedisplayskip}`.

Comment: @Mico: A trial and error number?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity See updated answer.